# Row_number mysql check compatibility

Tags: mysql, row-number

I am using row_number() in a query. Is there a way to check if this is supported before making a query? Otherwise it would fail.

```
SELECT stat_day, sum(total_count) as total_count
FROM (
            SELECT date(c_date) AS stat_day, media_id, artist, title, SUM(c_play) AS total_count 
               , row_number() over (partition by date(c_date) order by sum(c_play) desc) as 
            rn
            FROM {$statistics_table} 
            WHERE c_date > NOW() - INTERVAL %d DAY 
            GROUP BY date(c_date), media_id, artist, title
            HAVING SUM(c_play) > 0 
        ) t
WHERE t.rn <= %d
GROUP BY stat_day
ORDER BY stat_day
```

Comment: You can use:  ISNUMERIC(t.rn)  at sub query and then do the comparison ...

Answer (score 1):

You could check MySQL version before executing the actual query:

```
select version()
```

Window functions are supported in MySQL 8 or later.

Comment: When I do $wpdb->get_results("SELECT VERSION();"); I get VERSION(): '10.4.13-MariaDB'  How do I get mysql version?

Comment: You're using MariaDB, not MySQL. For MariaDB the version needs to be [10.2](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/changes-improvements-in-mariadb-102/) or higher.

Comment: Ok, but  I am looking to make some if statement not to execute the query if not supported. What would be returned if mysql was used for example?

Comment: You can't. Query has to be compiled as a whole, if statement and row_number together. If row_number function does not exist the whole statement will fail as a whole.